# read names of files from a folder but not allow to download

Tags: list, .htaccess, download, directory

I need to list names of files in a folder to show logged-in-users and allow only them to download. I could do downloading part by creating an .htacces as follows:

```
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from All
Allow from None
```

However, i stuck at reading names of the files in the folder because of permissions. Whenever i tried to use scandir or opendir, it gives permission errors. Now folder permission is : 774. Is there a way to get names of the files? Or should i try something else to get the names?

Comment: Can't you allow the user who execute php? Or the localhost ip?

Comment: only 1 user i am allowed to manage on the server. localhost ip did not work.